# SQL Oracle - Different count of all table if one particular column exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following script to count all line of every table for a specific owner. It works perfectly.
However, some tables have a specific column called 'OLD' and other don't...
My current script does not take into account if this column exists or not:

```
DECLARE 
val NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR I IN (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables where owner='myowner') LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM myowner.' || i.table_name INTO val;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.table_name || ';' || val );
END LOOP;
END;
```

So what I would like to add is something like:
if the OLD column exists, take it in account when OLD=0 (where OLD=0), if it does not exist keep doing the 'normal' count without taking this column into account.
Hope I've been clear enough ;)

Thanks a lot!

An example:
let's say I have 2 tables:

```
Table1 - columns A B C with the following data:
1 "test" "Steve"
2 "test2" "George"
Table2 - columns E F G OLD with the following data:
1 "test3" "Martin" 0
2 "test4" "Lucas" 0
3 "test5" "Marley" 0
4 "test6" "Bob" 55
```

The result should then be:

> Table1;2 -> there was not the 'OLD' column so I made a simples count
>   which returned 2
>
> Table2;3 -> there was the 'OLD' column so I made a count where OLD=0
>   and it returned then 3

Comment: Huh?  Do not understand. Please show an example with data.

Comment: let's say I have 2 tables:

`Table1 - columns A B C with the following data:
1 "test" "Steve"
2 "test2" "George"
Table2 - columns E F G OLD with the following data:
1 "test3" "Martin" 0
2 "test4" "Lucas" 0
3 "test5" "Marley" 0
4 "test6" "Bob" 55`

The result should then be:
Table1;2 -> there was not the 'OLD' column so I made a simples count which returned 2 
Table2;3 -> there was the 'OLD' column so I made a count where OLD=0 and it returned then 3

Comment: PLease edit question and put sample in question text.  Very hard to read in comments.  Thanks.

Comment: just added into the question ;)

Comment: use view `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` the logic of script is similar to what you have

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE 
    val NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR I IN (
    select a.table_name, c.column_name
    from all_tables a
    left join all_tab_cols c 
    ON a.owner = c.owner and a.table_name = c.table_name and c.column_name = 'OLD'
    where  a.owner = 'MYOWNER'
) 
LOOP
    IF i.column_name IS NULL THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM MYOWNER.' || i.table_name INTO val;
    ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM MYOWNER.' || i.table_name 
                          || ' WHERE old = 0' INTO val;
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.table_name || ';' || val );
END LOOP;
END;
```